# Hosting cron job server on vercel

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, hosting, vercel

I have made a node js server which have a cron that run every midnight now i want it to host on vercel but i doubt it will not work as server on vercel sleep due to in activity so is there any way to host server with crons on vercel.

Comment: Check https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-setup-cron-jobs-on-vercel. That is the best way to use cronjobs on Vercel.